# How to force Angular material mat menu to start at the corner of the screen

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Material menu API allow us to play with the position of the box using `overlapTrigger` which covers the trigger (the button), and also `xPosition` and `yPosition` to move it relative to the trigger (the button) for example ('above', 'before' etc..) but I couldn't find a way to stick the menu to the corner of the screen.

here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5sh2y?file=src/app/app.component.html) with mat menu.
when I click menu button icon I need the menu to show at the corner of the screen, left or right.

thank you!

Comment: We need additionnal information for your need. Which corner is it ? If it is top left, does that mean you want the overlay to be above the button that displays it ?

Comment: is this what you're looking for: `<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="true">`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use absolute values or play around with its options. Maybe this helps you:

```
::ng-deep.cdk-overlay-pane{
  transform: translate(80px, 70px);
}
```

Choose the values that suit you best.

Comment: thank you so much!! kyour solution did work for me. I use the [overlapTrigger]="true on the mat-menu and with your solution like that `::ng-deep.cdk-overlay-pane { transorm: translate(-8px, -16px) }`

Answer (score 0):

The material menu element use `.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box` class to display the overlay, where your mat menu will start. So in your styles.css add this to set your mat-menu at the top left corner

```
.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box{
  top:0 !important;
  left:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexis, I tried your solution and it didn't work, I also added `position: absolute` and `z-index: 2000`, BTW, using  `!important` is not recommended because it can affects other parts of the app, I still need a better solution.

Comment: @user12163165 No it will not leak into other CSS if you prefix it with your component-name like this: `:host your-component-name .cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box { css }`